# Pathauto deactivate when I use node_save($node)

Tags: 7, nodes, path-aliases

I'm trying to save a node code wise (like I've done a dozen times before), but for some reason, my custom URL given with the Pathauto module, disappears... The `Generate automatic URL alias` checkbox is checked and Drupal ignores my custom URL...

I've tried to give a custom URL with the URL-alias like:

```
$path = 'events/blablabla';
$node->path = array('alias' => $path);
node_save($node);
```

But that didn't work out either. So I'm wondering what do I do wrong. As far as I can see, there seems to be a bug in the module, but I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set:

```
$node->path = array('alias' => $path, 'pathauto' => FALSE);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

As [this similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51099/disable-pathauto-for-nodes-created-with-migrate-module) points out, its as easy as:

```
  $node->path['pathauto'] = 0;
```