# Disable pathauto for nodes created with migrate module

Tags: 7, path-aliases, migrations

I'm using [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) to import a bunch of nodes and I want to set the path alias during the migration. I am able to import the path alias just fine like so:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('path', 'url_alias');
```

When I look at the imported nodes I see the correct path in the `path` field, but the `Generate automatic URL alias` checkbox is still checked which means the setting is getting ignored.

How do I disable that setting on the node during migration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You basically need to make sure the `$node` object is passed in with `pathauto` set to false when it is saved.

In your migration class:

```
function prepare(&$row) {
  $row->path['pathauto'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the `Generate automatic URL alias` is still checked.

Comment: But I tried your suggestion in the prepare() method instead of prepareRow() and it worked! If you edit your post then I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Edited--got the wrong method the first time around :)

Answer (score 8):

```
$this->addFieldMapping('pathauto')->defaultValue(0);
```

Works for me.
Pathauto: Perform aliasing (set to 0 to prevent alias generation during migration 
See 'drush ma' + name of your class for full description

Answer (score 0):

If you'll sometimes but not always have an incoming path alias, then here's how you can trigger pathauto only when you haven't set an alias.

First, in the constructor, map both `path` and `pathauto`:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('path', 'path');
$this->addFieldMapping('pathauto', 'pathauto');
```

Then, in `::prepareRow()`, set the `pathauto` property depending on whether there's an incoming `path` value:

```
public function prepareRow($row) {
  parent::prepareRow($row);

  if (!empty($row->path)) {
    $row->pathauto = 0;
  }
  else {
    $row->pathauto = 1;
  }

}
```

The result is that if you've explicitly passed in a path that will be used for the alias, while if you haven't Pathauto will kick in.